# ASP.NET FileUpload control retrieving server path not local path

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, file-upload

I am currently having a problem when uploading a file using a file upload control in asp.net

I have published my page using IIS on a remote server and I am accessing that link on my local computer.

Currently when im trying to upload a file I get an error saying that path not found meaning its looking for the file path that is on my pc, on the server which of course doesn't exist.

How do I get this to get the path from my pc because im trying to copy/saveAs the file from my pc to the server.

**My code**:

```
 String pathCombine = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, Path.GetFileName(file));

 File.Copy(sourcePath, pathCombine);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is uploading the file and where the error is occurring?

Comment: @DiskJunky Please check short edited code above.

Comment: We'll need more to go on than that - we need context. In order to diagnose we need to see what's happening around your code, how your file upload is configured and, preferably the full action/event that uploads the file.

Comment: the server is only given a file with the same name as it had on your pc - it knows not where you got it from

Comment: Most (all?) browsers hide the full path for protection. There's no reason one should know the full path.

Comment: Exactly @BugFinder , it will not know until you give it a source which is what I gave it and the destination of which is the pathCombined in my case.
So its looking sourcePath on the server of which it will not be found. hence the error. How do I go about

Comment: Why do you even need the source path? You should have a `IFormFile`, `HttpPostedFileBase` or similar object which contains the file contents.

Comment: If i were you i would use FILESTREAM so you don't have to access the filesystem of the server directly